# Keras ValueError: expected dense_1 to have shape (3,) but got array with shape (4,)

Tags: keras

I've been trying to figure out how to use Keras when reading data from a .csv[1]. I have the following code:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv("iris.csv", header=None)
dataset = dataframe.values
X = dataset[:, 0:4].astype(float)
Y = dataset[:, 4]

# encode class values as integers
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(Y)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y)
# convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded)
one_hot_y = keras.utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)

X_train = X[:100]
X_test = X[50:]

Y_train = one_hot_y[:100]
Y_test = one_hot_y[50:]

print(X_train.shape)


# define baseline model
def baseline_model():
    # create model
    model = keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(8, input_shape=(4, ), activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model = baseline_model()

history = model.fit(X_train, X_test, epochs=5)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(Y_train, Y_test)
print('Test accuracy:', test_acc)
```

However, when I run this, I get the error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (3,) but got array with shape (4,)
```

I find this odd as I was sure to set input_shape=(4, ). Any help with this would be appreciated.

[1] The CSV looks as follows:

5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
...

Comment: You need to edit the error as its showing error in 2nd dense layer and you have posted it to be in 1st dense layer

Comment: I simply copied the error I received and can assure you it appeared as "dense_1".

Comment: Actually, I said that because I tried to reproduce the error and error was same but in dense_2. But that doesn't matter, since problem is solved anyways. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only 3 output neurons, but the data you are using obviously has 4 classes, so you need to change this line:

```
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

from 3 output classes to 4 output classes:

```
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
```